# What is List Node? Why return statement of List Node returns array instead of a Node?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Can someone please explain to me what is List Node and why/when it is declared as ListNode [] A = new ListNode[100] ? Below solution the question is to find the middle node for singly lined list. Return statement is 'return A[i/2]'. Answer is [3,4,5]. How A[i/2] returns in form of array?

Input:
[1,2,3,4,5]
Output : [3,4,5]

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode middleNode(ListNode head) {
        ListNode [] A = new ListNode[100];
        int i = 0;
        while (head.next != null){   
                A[i] = head;
                head = head.next;
                i++; 
        }
        
      return A[i/2];
        
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't return an array. It returns the middle node, just as the method name suggests. What `ListNode` is doesn't actually matter here as long as it has a `next` member of type `ListNode`, but it's fairly obvious.

Comment: "ListNode" is not a standard class. If you haven't created it, it must be something that your teacher/coworker has created.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your help.